# Unsteady state process for first law of thermodynamics with changing boundries

Tags: thermodynamics

Firstly , this is not an homework question .I tried to solve this question to understand the concept.

[image]

I made the following attempt to solve this question.However I couldn't solve after exit valve is opened.Can you give me a hint or say my mistakes? 
From which boundry should I start to solve easily ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take as the system the air in the tank.  Applying the open-system version of the first law of thermodynamics to this process, you have:

$$\Delta U=n_fu_f-n_iu_i=-p_f(V_f-V_i)+(n_f-n_i)h_s$$where $n_i$ is the initial number of moles of air in the tank, $n_f$ is the final number of moles of air in the tank, $u_f$ is the final internal energy per mole of air in the tank, $u_i$ is the initial internal energy per mole of air in the tank, $p_f$ is the air pressure from the supply line, $V_f$ is the final volume of air in the tank, $V_i$ is the initial volume of air in the tank, and $h_s=u_i+RT_i$ is the molar enthalpy of the air in the supply line.

The equation I wrote leads to a final answer which matches the correct answer given in the book.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear answer.I think that I  am not good at defining the system and its properties .Therefore ,I have to make more practice . .

Comment: I commend you for articulation of your value for practice.  In my judgment, the importance of practice in mastering a new scientific subject can not be overemphasized.